# Comparing two rows in mysql and manipulating according to result

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have an Answer Key of questions Q1, Q2, and so on. Also, I have responses of the same questions from many students. Is there anyway I can compare the responses of each student with the answer key and store the marks obtained (say 4, 0, -1 for correct, omitted and incorrect) in a separate table?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: read a tutorial about relational databases

Comment: i have the response table and a separate answer key table. now i would want to loop smthing like 'IF(response.Q1=ansKey.Q1, 4, (IF(response.Q1<>ansKey.Q1, -1,0)))' over all the fields in each row and save that accordingly in a separate table. Hope you understand the prob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make your task easier with redesigning your database. Rather than trying to loop over columns, put the questions in rows and use the power of an SQL JOIN... Make a questions table something like this

```
create table questions(
question_id int,
question_description VARCHAR(100),
rightanswer varchar(100)
)
```

Now get your student responses:

```
create table student_responses(
student_id int,
question_id int,
answer varchar(100)
)
```

Now your output:

```
SELECT student_id,COUNT(*) as numberofrightanswers FROM
student_responses sr
INNER JOIN
questions q on q.question_id = sr.question_id
where answer = rightanswer
GROUP BY student_id
```

Of course, you can use any logic you like for scoring the answers.